How to fetch accurate global lock status for an account using Meta Wikimedia API
I'm creating a tool that uses the Meta Wikimedia API to check the status of various accounts (active vs dormant, editors to various spaces etc)
I've noticed that some accounts are locked globally, e.g.: https://meta.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:CentralAuth&target=Lamberto%20Mosca

I can't find a way to get this information for an account using the API however. The following query:
 https://meta.wikimedia.org/w/api.php
    ?action=query
    &meta=globaluserinfo
    &guiuser=Lamberto%20Mosca
    &guiprop=groups|merged
    &format=json

returns:
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "globaluserinfo": {
            "home": "itwiki",
            "id": 70355745,
            "registration": "2022-08-06T15:46:57Z",
            "name": "Lamberto Mosca",
            "locked": "",
            "groups": [],
            "merged": [
                {
                    "wiki": "commonswiki",
                    "url": "https://commons.wikimedia.org",
                    "id": 11460287,
                    "timestamp": "2022-08-06T18:28:11Z",
                    "method": "login",
                    "editcount": 1,
                    "registration": "2022-08-06T18:28:11Z"
                },
                {
                    "wiki": "enwiki",
                    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org",
                    "id": 44308468,
                    "timestamp": "2022-08-06T15:46:58Z",
                    "method": "login",
                    "editcount": 43,
                    "registration": "2022-08-06T15:46:58Z"
                },
                {
                    "wiki": "itwiki",
                    "url": "https://it.wikipedia.org",
                    "id": 2291286,
                    "timestamp": "2022-08-06T15:46:57Z",
                    "method": "new",
                    "editcount": 0,
                    "registration": "2022-08-06T15:46:56Z"
                },
                {
                    "wiki": "loginwiki",
                    "url": "https://login.wikimedia.org",
                    "id": 75811202,
                    "timestamp": "2022-08-06T15:47:56Z",
                    "method": "login",
                    "editcount": 0,
                    "registration": "2022-08-06T15:47:56Z"
                },
                {
                    "wiki": "metawiki",
                    "url": "https://meta.wikimedia.org",
                    "id": 35888229,
                    "timestamp": "2022-08-06T15:47:56Z",
                    "method": "login",
                    "editcount": 0,
                    "registration": "2022-08-06T15:47:56Z"
                },
                {
                    "wiki": "wikidatawiki",
                    "url": "https://www.wikidata.org",
                    "id": 5812243,
                    "timestamp": "2022-08-10T14:39:31Z",
                    "method": "login",
                    "editcount": 0,
                    "registration": "2022-08-10T14:39:31Z"
                },
                {
                    "wiki": "wikimaniawiki",
                    "url": "https://wikimania.wikimedia.org",
                    "id": 74454,
                    "timestamp": "2022-08-08T06:47:22Z",
                    "method": "login",
                    "editcount": 0,
                    "registration": "2022-08-08T06:47:22Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

with the "locked" field unpopulated. How can I fetch a response that shows the account as Globally locked, together with the date/admin performing the lock, tags + comment?
